# Adding meta_box to WordPress. Cancel form submission

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I added a new meta_box to WordPress.

I have a button that when pressed it copies a string to the computer's memory.

The problem is that the code is probably in form because I see the following line up:

```
<form id = 'adv-settings' method = 'post'>
```

What happens is that when you click the button, it sends the form and refreshes the page. I want to cancel this option and it will not be sent.

This is my code that I added to the functions.php file within the theme:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_meta_boxes' );

function add_meta_boxes()
{
    add_meta_box( 
        'woocommerce-order-my-custom', 
        __( 'COPY' ), 
        'order_my_custom', 
        'shop_order', 
        'side', 
        'default' 
    );
}
function order_my_custom()
{
?>
</form>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copy to clipboard</button>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('I want to get copied into my clipboard')">Copy to clipboard</button>


<script>
function copyToClipboard() {
    let textToCopy      = "I want to get copied into my clipboard",
        urlInput = document.createElement( "input" );
    document.body.appendChild( urlInput );
    urlInput.setAttribute( "value", textToCopy );
    if ( navigator.userAgent.match( /ipad|ipod|iphone/i ) ) {
        let contentEditable      = urlInput.contentEditable,
            readOnly             = urlInput.readOnly,
            range                = document.createRange(),
            windowSelection      = window.getSelection();
        urlInput.contentEditable = !0;
        urlInput.readOnly        = !1;
        range.selectNodeContents( urlInput );
        windowSelection.removeAllRanges();
        windowSelection.addRange( range );
        urlInput.setSelectionRange( 0, 999999 );
        urlInput.contentEditable = contentEditable;
        urlInput.readOnly        = readOnly
    } else urlInput.select();
    document.execCommand( "copy" );
    document.body.removeChild( urlInput );
    alert( "Successfully copied to clipboard" );
}
</script>
<?php
}
```

can anyone help me ? Thank you

Comment: change this `<button onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copy to clipboard</button>` to `<button type='button' onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copy to clipboard</button>`

Comment: add `type='button'` attribute

Comment: It works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. Add `type='button'` attribute.

```
function order_my_custom(){
    ?>
    </form>
    <button type="button" onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copy to clipboard</button>
    <button type="button"  onclick="copyToClipboard('I want to get copied into my clipboard')">Copy to clipboard</button>


    <script>
    function copyToClipboard() {
        let textToCopy      = "I want to get copied into my clipboard",
            urlInput = document.createElement( "input" );
        document.body.appendChild( urlInput );
        urlInput.setAttribute( "value", textToCopy );
        if ( navigator.userAgent.match( /ipad|ipod|iphone/i ) ) {
            let contentEditable      = urlInput.contentEditable,
                readOnly             = urlInput.readOnly,
                range                = document.createRange(),
                windowSelection      = window.getSelection();
            urlInput.contentEditable = !0;
            urlInput.readOnly        = !1;
            range.selectNodeContents( urlInput );
            windowSelection.removeAllRanges();
            windowSelection.addRange( range );
            urlInput.setSelectionRange( 0, 999999 );
            urlInput.contentEditable = contentEditable;
            urlInput.readOnly        = readOnly
        } else urlInput.select();
        document.execCommand( "copy" );
        document.body.removeChild( urlInput );
        alert( "Successfully copied to clipboard" );
    }
    </script>
    <?php
}
```